# Plot multiple values with matplotlib without loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have two nested lists with the values for the x-axis and y-axis that I want to plot in the same figure.

Whith a for loop to iterate through the values produces the expected plot, but for large lists is relatively slow. So I was looking for the same functionality but without the loop, which I thought matplotlib could handle, but the plot is not what I was expecting.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = [[11, 20], [31, 31], [32, 33]]
ys = [[1, 10], [3, 4], [6, 10]]
```

With a loop the figure is OK:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, x in enumerate(xs):
    ax.plot(x, ys[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But just giving the lists to matplotlib, doesn't generate the same plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image: enter code here]

What would be the proper way for doing this whithout a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the list of line segments is large, you can improve performance by using a `LineCollection` instead of multiple calls to `plt.plot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as mcoll

xs = [[11, 20], [31, 31], [32, 33]]
ys = [[1, 10], [3, 4], [6, 10]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html
prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']
segments = np.array(list(zip(xs, ys))).swapaxes(1,2)
line_segments = mcoll.LineCollection(segments, colors=colors)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)
ax.set(xlim=(10,34), ylim=(0,11))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here are some additional examples that use `LineCollection`:

- [how to make multicolored lines](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)
- [more multicolored lines generated with a nice utility function](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb)
- [a venerable and pithy example from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068758/190597)
- [how to add a legend to a LineCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881647/190597)

---

`LineCollection` expects the first argument to be a sequence of the form `[(pt0, pt1), (pt2, pt3), (pt4, pt5), ...]`, where each `pt` is of the form `(x-coord, y-coord)`.
Matplotlib will then render this `LineCollection` as line segments

```
pt0 --> pt1 
pt2 --> pt3
pt4 --> pt5
etc.
```

---

The reason why `swapaxes` was used in the code above is because `zip(xs, ys)` 
creates pairs of the form `((x0, x1), (y0, y1))`, whereas
`LineCollection` wants pairs of points to be of the form `((x0, y0), (x1, y1))`.

Comment: Sounds good. Haven't heard about `LineCollection` before, but it's definitely more efficient. One thing I noticed is that you have to explicitly set xlim/ylim, otherwise the figure is just shown around 0:1. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Unlike the higher-level plotting functions, (e.g. `plt.plot`, `plt.scatter`, `plt.imshow`, etc), the `mcoll.LineCollection` is a lower-level artist. It is added directly to the axes, `ax`, but does not alter the axes' xlim and ylim. So you have to set them yourself.